# HAProxy encode url for querystring

Tags: haproxy, url, encoding, querystring

I have a system that needs to preserve the original referer over multiple redirects. To achieve this I'm trying to write the referer to the URL query string.
I already got that working (somewhat).

```
http-request set-query ref=%[req.hdr(Referer)]&%[query]
```

The only problem is that URLs in the querystring have to be encoded. Unfortunately HAProxy only has a url_dec function.

Is there any easy way in which I can encode the URL?

Comment: That depends, I suspect, on how you define "easy."  If HAProxy 1.6 or later, it should be possible to write a custom converter function in Lua to do the url-encoding and then use that converter in your configuration.  That will be slightly tricky since Lua strings are bytes (not characters) so (afaik) UTF-8 would have to be handled manually, but seems within the realm of feasibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a built-in for this, but it's easily done with the Lua integration in HAProxy 1.6 and later.

Create a Lua file, let's say `/etc/haproxy/lua/url_escape.lua`.

I found some examples online of url-escaping ("encoding") in Lua, but none of them I found in a cursory search appeared to be UTF-8 aware.  So, I wrote this:

```
function url_escape(str)
    local escape_next = 0;
    local escaped = str:gsub('.',function(char)
        local ord = char:byte(1);
        if(escape_next > 0) then
            escape_next = escape_next - 1;
        elseif(ord <= 127) then               -- single-byte utf-8
            if(char:match("[0-9a-zA-Z%-%._~]")) then -- only these do not get escaped
                return char;
            elseif char == ' ' then           -- also space, becomes '+'
                return '+';
            end;
        elseif(ord >= 192 and ord < 224) then -- utf-8 2-byte
            escape_next = 1;
        elseif(ord >= 224 and ord < 240) then -- utf-8 3-byte
            escape_next = 2;
        elseif(ord >= 240 and ord < 248) then -- utf-8 4-byte
            escape_next = 3;
        end;
        return string.format('%%%02X',ord);
    end);
    return escaped;
end;

core.register_converters('url_escape',url_escape);
```

Configure HAProxy to load this, in the `global` section of `/etc/haproxy.cfg`:

```
global
    lua-load /etc/haproxy/lua/url_escape.lua
```

Now, you have a converter called `lua.url_escape`, that works like other converters -- it's added with a `,` to the end of the expression that provides its input.

```
http-request set-query ref=%[req.hdr(Referer),lua.url_escape]&%[query]
```

Test:

```
curl -v http://example.com/my-page.html?lol=cat -H 'Referer: http://example.org/cats/Shrödinger.html'
```

The request seen by the back-end:

```
GET /my-page.html?ref=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Fcats%2FShr%C3%B6dinger.html&lol=cat HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
Referer: http://example.org/cats/Shrödinger.html
```

`Shrödinger` is correctly escaped here with ö (U+00D6) having two bytes in `Shr%C3%B6dinger`.  3 and 4 byte characters also appear to be correctly handled.  Byte sequences with the high bit on that don't correspond to valid UTF-8 characters will also be escaped.

Note that if you are logging the query string with HAProxy, the modified query is never logged -- the original request is what makes it to the log output.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

There is a built-in converter now: https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/2-2r1/onepage/#url_enc

You can use it in an `http-request` directive like so:

```
http-request redirect location https://example.com/login?r=%[url,url_enc()] if !{ req.hdr(x-consumer-username) -m found }
```

In this example, the originally requested URL is URL encoded and added to the querystring at key `r`.

Original answer:

The HAProxy folks have a blog post section for this exact use-case:

https://www.haproxy.com/blog/5-ways-to-extend-haproxy-with-lua/#converters

Seems like something that should be built-in IMO, however.