# How to encode url in haproxy

Tags: haproxy, lua

I am new to haproxy and I wanted to know the best way to encode the URL in haproxy.

```
http-request redirect code 302 location https://testservice.com/login?service=abc&redirect_uri=https://login.serivce.com?next_url=%[hdr(host)]%[capture.req.uri,regsub(&,%26,g)] unless cookie
```

In the above statement, I want to encode anything that comes after redirect_url,

Can someone suggest me, please?

Comment: what do you want to solve?

Comment: @djdomi, In the above example, I want to encode the content present after the redirect_url parameter, when the redirection happens.

Comment: its looks for me like an [X-and-Y-Problem](https://faq-database.de/doku.php?id=en:x-and-y-problem) please be more specific, what is the use case you want to have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HAProxy encode url for querystring](https://serverfault.com/questions/910336/haproxy-encode-url-for-querystring)